# Template literal type inside object property falls back to primitive type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, template-literals

Given the following code:

```js
type Id = 1 | 2;

type Obj = {
    [key in `charge_${Id}_a` | `charge_${Id}_b`]: string
};
    
function func(id: Id) {
    const obj: Obj = {
        [`charge_${id}_a`]: "a",
        [`charge_${id}_b`]: "b",
    }

    return obj;
}
```

I would expect `obj` comply with `Obj`, but instead I'm getting the following error:

> Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Obj': charge_1_a, charge_2_a, charge_1_b, charge_2_b(2739)

Meaning, the Typescript infers `obj` as `{ [x: string]: string; }` and not as `Obj`.

### [See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJlAvFAjFAPlATAbgFB6iRQDyARgFZJQDeeUDUA2gNYQhQCWAdlAAYBjABYBDAE4BzCAH0AJDXgBfaSL4Z+w8VLkK4ysnwC6ALigBnYGJ4S8i-Iyh4AZgFduA4JwD2vV+4AUnHCm8ACUtPSMAj4WUF6UpuRUyHQODkyCopIy8kHKqiZQAEQiRQA0kWnMmVo5NHnSBoVFZOWVUIoEDmIQwC5ivPEU+IpAA)

Comment: it should not comply, as far as I can see. `const obj: Obj = { charge_1_b: "foo" };` this doesn't compile, since it is missing  `charge_1_a`, `charge_2_a`, `charge_2_b`. Try it yourself. I get the problem, TS infers ````charge_${id}_a```` as `string`, not as `charge_1_a | charge_2_a`

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you'll be able to infer something other than the index type `{[x: string]: string}` for an object with computed properties, but there's also an issue with your `Obj` type. You define it as one object containing the fields for all `id` values, but looking at `func` it seems you'd want a union with one object per `id`: https://tsplay.dev/Wv8QRN

Answer (score 0):

> Meaning, the Typescript infers obj as { [x: string]: string; } and not
> as Obj.

***NO*** it is not bcuz of that. the reason is bcuz there are rules and one of them says

> You can only use types when indexing, meaning you can’t use a const to make a variable reference:

now getting at yow example you have some like this

```
type Obj = {
    [key in `charge_${Id}_a` | `charge_${Id}_b`]: string
};
```

you is breaking the rule because `charge_${Id}_a` and `charge_${Id}_b` are two string literals which means they is constants, to be able to do so you'll need to make them times

```
type Obj = {
    [x: string]: string
};
```

but then whats the whole point of doing that people will be open to insert which eva they want to prevent that just follow the rules

```
const Options = `charge_${Id}_a` | `charge_${Id}_b`;

type Obj = {
    [key in Options]: string
};
```

wait, didnt I just say that you need types for indexing, not constants, well yes, thats why we need the unfamous `keyof`

```
function func(id: Id) {
    const obj: Obj = {
        [`charge_${id}_a` as keyof Options]: "a",
        [`charge_${id}_b` as keyof Options]: "b",
    }

    return obj;
}
```